# Bound of Confluent Hypergeometric Function: $M(1;1+1/p;-(x^p)/p)\leq x^{-p}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds, hypergeometric-function

This question concerns Kummer's confluent Hypergeometric function $M$, also denoted as $_1F_1$.
Recall that $$M(a;b;z)=\hspace{0.1cm} _1F_1(a;b;z)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(a)_n}{(b)_n}\frac{z^k}{k!}.$$
Consider $x\geq0, p\in (0,1)$, I would like to prove that there exists $x_0>0$ such that: $$f(x)=M\left(1;1+\frac{1}{p};-\frac{x^p}{p}\right)\leq x^{-p},\hspace{0.2cm} \forall x\geq x_0.$$
Plotting $f$ and $x^{-p}$ numerically, this conjecture seems to be true and sharp, nevertheless, I was unable to prove it.

$\textbf{PS:}$ This problem arises from trying to bound a generalization of the Dawson's integral $F(p,x)=e^{-x^p}\int_0^x e^{t^p}dt$ for the case $p<1$. Since $F(p,x)=xM(1;1+\frac{1}{p};-x^p)$, then $p^{1/p}F(p,p^{-1/p}x)=xf(x)$, so in these terms, the inequality is $$p^{1/p}F(p,p^{-1/p}x)\leq x^{1-p}.$$ On the other hand $$F(p,x)=e^{-x^p}\frac{x}{p}\Gamma(1/p)\gamma^*(1/p,-x^p)=\frac{x}{p}\Gamma(1/p)\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-x^p)^k}{\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{p}+k)},$$
where $\gamma^*$ is the holomorphic extension of the lower incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: We have an integral representation
$$f(x) = \frac 1 p \int_0^1 (1 - t)^{1/p - 1} e^{-x^p t/p} dt.$$
Applying Laplace's method, we expand $(1 - t)^{1/p - 1}$ about $t = 0$ and integrate termwise over $[0, \infty)$. We obtain
$$f(x) - x^{-p} \sim -(1 - p) x^{-2 p}$$
for $x \to \infty$, so, for any given $p$, $f(x) - x^{-p}$ is negative for all $x$ greater than some $x_0(p)$.

Comment: Hi @Maxim, thanks for your answer, I read about the integral representation and I think is $\Gamma(1/p)$ instead of $p$ in the fraction before the integral. Besides, if we define $\alpha=1/p-1>0$, did you expand $$(1-t)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{\alpha}{n}(-1)^nt^n?$$ I did it like that, then integrating termwise I had to integrate $\int_0^1 t^ne^{-\frac{x^p}{p}t}dt$ and I bounded it by $(px^{-p})^{n+1}n!$, maybe is a bad bound but I couldn't finish it, mainly because I didn't get how to use the Laplace's Method in this case.

Comment: No, the factor before the integral is not $1/\Gamma(1/p)$. See the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful lemma, according to this, I get that $f(x)\sim x^{-p}-(1-p)px^{-2p}$, nevertheless, it is not so clear how to obtain that $f(x)-x^{-p}\sim -(1-p)px^{-2p}$, given that the asymptotic equivalence is a little bit messy with the sums.

Comment: If $\sim$ means asymptotic equivalence, then $y \sim x^{-p} + x^{-2 p} \Leftrightarrow y \sim x^{-p}$. So writing $y \sim x^{-p} + x^{-2 p}$ may be useful only if there is an implicit assumption about the remainder. See the Wikipedia article on asymptotic expansions (linked from the article on Watson's lemma) for an explanation of the $y \sim \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \phi_k(x)$ notation.

Comment: Now I see that the $\sim$ notation is different for asymptotic expansions, in that context we can obtain that $$f(x)-x^{-p}=\mathcal{O}(x^{-2p}).$$
This means that there exists $C>0$, such that $|f(x)-x^{-p}|\leq Cx^{-2p}$ for $x$ large enough, which differs from your original solution and does not allow the conclusion that I would like.