# Prove that $\int_0^1 e^{-tu}(1-u)^{\alpha}du\leq t^{-1}$ for $\alpha,t>0$

Tags: calculus, upper-lower-bounds, hypergeometric-function, bounds-of-integration

Let $\alpha>0$, I need to prove that there exists $t_0>0$ such that $$\int_0^1 e^{-tu}(1-u)^{\alpha}du\leq t^{-1}, \forall t>t_0.$$ I received help and found that by [Watson's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) you could obtain that: $$\int_0^1 e^{-tu}(1-u)^{\alpha}du\sim t^{-1} \text{ as } t\rightarrow+\infty.$$
Nevertheless, that does not concretely solve the inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_0^1 e^{-tu}(1-u)^{\alpha} \, du \le \int_0^1 e^{-tu}\, du = \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t} < \frac 1t
$$
holds for all $t > 0$.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Watson's lemma is [also a valid way](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481555) to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realized that in my case $\alpha>-\frac{1}{2}$ and that changes the direct proof. In fact $$\int_0^1\frac{e^{-tu}}{\sqrt{1-u}}du=\frac{2F(\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{t}}.$$ Where F is the Dawson's integral. To prove my statement I would like to say that $F(t)\leq \frac{1}{2t}$ in the long term but the asymptotic expansion of $F$ for large $t$ is $\frac{1}{2t}+\mathcal{O}(t^{-3})$.